# Extract raw CSS/SCSS file and use output in JS

Tags: javascript, css, file, webpack, sass

I'm making simple components library. Basic project setup based on Webpack.

I've got all my components in separate folders with structure like below.

```
test/
|- test.html
|- test.scss
|- test.md
```

I'm loading HTML files in my app.js as string and creating previews and code snippets, but I can't load my SCSS files as raw content.

Here is the CodeSandox link with my project setup: [preview link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-shadow-9b1w0)

**What I need?** 
I need my .scss files **content** available in app.js as text, so I'll be able to generate snippets in code blocks available for a user. 
**I don't need help with compilation, it's all good there.**

*Thanks!*

Comment: How MiniCssExtractPlugin help you here? You say you need your styles in javascript no? This plugin extract all css and create a .css file for them, afterwards you can't use them directly in your .js files

Comment: I want a scss compilator to work as it is at the moment I've got all the styles from main file and components compiled to one css file as intended.
I need is to have **content** of my scss files available in app.js file so I can print that out for the end user.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @admcfajn I've added link to preview in the main post.